# Align `dt` and `dd` on the last line

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<dl>
    <dt>some text</dt>
    <dd>12.45</dd>
    <dt>some larger text</dt>
    <dd>46.05</dd>
    <dt>some even larger text</dt>
    <dd>46.05</dd>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</dl>
```

...and this CSS:

```
dl {
    width: 120px;
}
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
dd {
    float: right;
}
```

And it's producing this (I added some unimportant extra styles to show what's going on):

[image: wrong alignment]

The problem is, the last `dd` is not aligned to the last `dt`. **How can I make the number align to the last line of the text?** (The second `dt`/`dd` is fine)

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/R26sX/) with my predicament.

**EDIT**: To be perfectly clear, this is what I want:

[image: corrected]

Comment: You could set the top margin of that element to have a negative margin to pull it up: `<dd style="margin-top: -20px;">46.05</dd>`.

Comment: I'll never know which items do that, so I can't style only some of them.

Comment: Is the list width fixed?

Comment: Yes, it will always have a fixed width

Comment: probably this is exactly what you looking for: http://www.pmob.co.uk/search-this/list-with-dotted-leader-dltest.htm

Comment: Close, but not quite there yet. My box is pretty small, so the text lines should be able to reach the right border of the box. In your link, it behaves like a table.

Comment: Open link -> firebug -> `.inner` -> `width: 150px;` i think, this is exactly what in last screen, except dotes

Comment: In firebug, locate a `dd`, and disable its `padding`. Then it gets pretty close, but sometimes the text is hidden by the "Dish X"

Comment: `padding` is the most important. Change it from `0 5em 0 0` to max width of your float number + few px

Comment: well that's exactly the issue, I want the text to be able to occupy the same "column" as the number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Brief moan

A flexible approach to this has been a known gap in CSS for 15 years. It would be solved but for a 15-year-old Firefox bug relating to CSS 2, and may have been possible if the `tab-stops` specification suggested 17 years ago ever got off the ground. See the updates below for more details if you're interested.

### A limited solution

I found a few different ways of doing this without changing the markup by using pseudo-elements. All of them have significant drawbacks, but if you can reliably establish a maximum width for the `dd` text, this is probably the best way:

```
dl {
    line-height: 1.3em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 140px;
}

dt {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

dd {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -1.3em; /* i.e. minus line-height */
}

dt:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3.5em; /* Max width of a dd element */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/p4mMa/3/

Here, the `:after` pseudo-element takes up extra space in each `dt`, causing it to break onto a new line if there won't be enough room for the `dd` element to fit on the end of the current one. (You will also need to reset your margins and padding on the elements, I've left that stuff out for concision.)

### Alternatives

Other approaches I considered included `display: inline` on the `dt` and using the `:before` pseudo-element with `display: block` to break the line ([WebKit doesn't like this](http://jsfiddle.net/p4mMa/1/)) and the same approach, but using `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%` to appease WebKit browsers ([works, but you have indelible empty lines before each `dt`](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/p4mMa/2/)).

It bears mentioning that IE7 and IE8 are out, since they don't support pseudo-elements. If you're up for progressive enhancement, just remove the negative margin on the `dd` element in a conditional stylesheet and the prices will always be displayed on a separate line in those browsers.

---

**UPDATE (2013-04-18):** I know this is an old answer, but a recent Twitter conversation reminded me of something I think is worth mentioning. There's another way of doing this that doesn't require guesstimating a width for the `dd`: [the little-known `display: run-in`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#run-in-boxes) essentially allows you to treat a block-level element as inline content of its next sibling. The only compromise is wrapping your `dd` content with a span; other than that, [it's a relatively elegant solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/p4mMa/8/) that works in *most* modern browsers—and even IE8!

The problem? [A **15-year-old** Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2056), filed on Christmas Eve 1998 and unlikely to be addressed any time soon.

It's understandable: [`run-in` boxes are "horribly underspecified"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2056#c34), there aren't so many use cases and there are more important/useful things to work on. Still, it seems to have slipped through the cracks to an extent, and I can't help but wonder if more people would use it given reliable support.

---

**UPDATE (2013-11-13):** This exact use case was described on a [list of suggested extensions to CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-CSS-potential#id1554439764) published by the W3C in December 1998. Also, way back in January 1997, Dave Raggett authored [proposal for a `tab-stops` property](http://www.w3.org/People/howcome/t/970224HTMLERB-CSS/WD-tabs-970117.html) that would have worked admirably here. Sadly, neither the use case nor the proposal gained much traction.

Comment: very nice! I don't care about IE7 and 8, these can see the horrible gap and when they complain I'll point them to the newest Chrome or FF

Comment: Glad it's what you're looking for. :) (If only there were some way in CSS to "pull" the `dd` into the `dt` this would have been trivial!)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem becomes no problem if you don't mind switching to `ul`/`li`/`span`:

http://jsbin.com/acunew/3/edit#html,live

```
<ul>
    <li>some text <span>12.45</span></li>
    <li>some larger text <span>46.05</span></li>
    <li>some even larger text <span>46.05</span></li>
</ul>
```

The new HTML isn't quite as semantic as yours was, but I think it's fine.

The CSS is almost the same:

```
ul {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    clear: both;
}
span {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Is it wrong to put the `<dd>` *inside* the `<dt>`? (like this `<dl><dt>some text <dd>12.45</dd></dt></dl>`, so it can probably be styled like your answer)

Comment: Unfortunately, it *is* wrong. [It's invalid HTML.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Faqodec%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0):

I think Zuazua's on the right track. I would add some javascript to detect which dt has a width that's greater than 120px. Then I would apply Zuazua's class to its sibling dd. Of course, I would change the name of the class to better suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I think j08691 was very close to the answer, you just need to use position relative and a negative margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/3UyKG/